# Mouse Events on QGraphicsview and Object Movement

Tags: qt

I implemented a Graphicsview in which I load an Image and the user can add different Item such as rectangle or line. The user has also the possibility to move these objects in the scene. Up to here everything is ok.

Now I tried to implement some mouse events in this way:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{

    if (obj == ui->graphicsView && enable_mouse_event==true)
    {
          if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
          {
              QMouseEvent *mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
              point_mouse = ui->graphicsView->mapFrom(ui->graphicsView, mouseEvent->pos());
              return true;
          }

          if (event->type() ==  QEvent::MouseMove)
          {
                  int scroll_x, scroll_y;
                  scroll_x = ui->graphicsView->horizontalScrollBar()->value();
                  scroll_y = ui->graphicsView->verticalScrollBar()->value();
                  QMouseEvent  *mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
                  point_mouse_move = ui->graphicsView->mapFrom(ui->graphicsView, mouseEvent->pos());
                  QRect rect(point_mouse_move.x()+scroll_x-50, point_mouse_move.y()+scroll_y-50, 100, 100);
                  zoom_image = image_clone.copy(rect);
                  ui->zoom_label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(zoom_image));
                  return true;
          }
    }

    return false
 }
```

with in MainWindow.cpp

```
ui->graphicsView->installEventFilter(this);
```

In this way the press event is recognized while the move event is recognized only on the border of the Qgraphicview object (the property mouseTracking is set to true) and I'm still able to move the other object.

To solve the problem of the move event I tried to modify the code by adding:

```
->viewport()
```

to the graphicview object.

In this way both the mouse events (press and move) work correctly but I'm no longer able to move the other objects (rect and line)

Any Idea how can I recognize all the mouse events and at the same time move the other objects??

thanks

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are trying to do, are you trying to re-implement QGraphicsItem ? Wouldn't it be easier to add QGraphicsRectItem, QGraphicsLineItem... ?

Comment: *In this way both the mouse events (press and move) work correctly but I'm no longer able to move the other objects (rect and line)*.. Maybe because you're filtering out the event so it never goes to the view? What happens if you return false instead?

Comment: That's the answer! what a stupid error! You are right thanks @thuga

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was filtering out the events and they never go to the window. Instead of setting the returns true just set the return false! 
Thanks to @thuga